# Symfony fosrestbundle url formming

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

My route file look like

```
#routing.yml
user:
    type: rest
    resource:     api.user.controller
    name_prefix:  api_
loan:
    type: rest
    resource:     api.loan.controller
    name_prefix:  api_
```

Api method defined as:

```
    /**
     * Get a single user.
     *
     * @ApiDoc(
     *   output = "AppBundle\Model\User",
     *   statusCodes = {
     *     200 = "Returned when successful",
     *     404 = "Returned when the user is not found"
     *   }
     * )
     *
     * @param int $id the user id
     *
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException when user not exist
     */
    public function getUserAction($id)
    {
        $repo = $this->model->getRepository(User::class);
        $user = $repo->find($id);

        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('User not found');
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

I'm getting url:

```
api_get__user  GET   ANY   ANY   /api/{id}/user
```

Want to have: /api/user/{id}

How I can fix that without adding `@Route` into annotation, because I'm using auto route naming.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the "name_prefix" you can just use "prefix" in `routing.yml`.

with the method

```
public function getUserAction($id) {}
```

and the configuration inside `MyBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml`:

```
user.controller:
    type: rest
    resource: "@MyBundle/Controller/UserController.php"
    prefix: 'api'
```

I get the generated route:

`get_user                   GET      ANY      ANY    /api/users/{id}`